# run cron job every minute between 7AM and 12AM

Tags: cron

I am attempting to run a cron job every minute between 7AM and 12PM the expression I am attempting to use is as follows:

```
*/1 7-24 * * *
```

which doesn't appear to run correctly.  I am fairly new to writing such expressions, could anyone point me in the right direction for what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean every minute between 7:00 and 12:00 (12pm, noon), use this:

```
* 7-12 * * *
```

If you want every minute between 7:00 and 24:00 (12am, midnight), use this:

```
* 7 * * *
```

Other combinations you can try here: [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_*)

First star already means **every minute**, so there is no need to manipulate this further.

Comment: my apologies I meant 7:00 am to 12:00am

Comment: In this case you can use my second example. If my above (updated) answer solves your problem, please accept it.